# Prove that $ \frac{1}{1*5} + \frac{1}{2*7} + \frac{1}{3*9}+... = \frac{8}{9} - \frac{2}{3}\ln(2) $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $ \frac{1}{1*5} + \frac{1}{2*7} + \frac{1}{3*9}+... = \frac{8}{9} - \frac{2}{3}\ln(2)$

I got the answer using the hint given in the question
 It mentioned to consider the integral$\int x^2 \ln(1-x^2)dx$.
I evaluated the integral by integration by parts.

Then I again evaluated by applying Taylor series. I equated both expressions and took limits of integration from 0 to 1 to obtain the result.

Is there any other way to solve this question? Without the hint, I would never have thought of considering that Integration.

What I tried: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i(2i+3)} = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}-\frac{2}{2i+3}$

But both of the above series diverge

Comment: Oh sorry . I have corrected it now

Comment: How do you all identify the question has been posted before?I mean, how to search and find the question?

Comment: Have a look at [How do you search for duplicates?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3258/42969). For your series, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi(2i%2B3)%7D%24&p=1) quickly finds an identical question.